# Should Form Names/URL Parameters be Different from their corresponding Column Names?

Tags: database-design, coding-style, naming-conventions

**Question**

I would like to get the community's opinion and workarounds on this matter.

Given a form

```
<form>
Employee ID <input type="text" name="employee_id"><br>
First name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
</form>
```

that maps to the table

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `employee_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
)
```

Is it a good or bad practice for the form elements to have names that matches their underlying table columns?

These are the considerations I am wrestling with:

**Pros**

An advantage of having the same names is that I can have a generic Data Access Object where you can just pass the form names and it can easily create the required SQL code.  Another is the ease of remembering what the correct column/form names are especially when the data is passed and stored in associative arrays.

**Cons**

Security. Though I'm no security expert, I feel that users (and hackers) do not have to know or surmise anything about the storage medium, and that includes the table and column names.  Another disadvantage is that if I have database naming conventions (ex. pk_employee_id instead of employee_id since the column is a primary key) then I may be forced to used those same conventions in my HTML and server side codes just so the names will match.

Thus

Given those considerations and others you can offer, can anyone enlighten me what's their stand and practice on this matter? If you think that the names should be different, how can one implement the name matching/conversions in code (perhaps, having a separate class to translate one into another)?

Comment: I consider the security reasons to be enough to warrant having different names however it also makes sense when you have a backend developer working with a frontend developer. The person creating the UI can name the form fields in a way that makes sense to them and the backend developer just needs to map those fields to the correct fields in the table. As for implementation - it could be done myriad ways.

Comment: Seems like any case is acceptable to you, am I right?  If you go with the different names, doesn't it seem overkill or tedious to perform extra lookups and name conversions before ANY data extraction/update? That may involve a giant array or a switch statement especially if you have many tables/columns. What would you do in your case?  Thanks

Comment: Many of the things we do in programming seem tedious - data validation comes immediately to mind. If those darn users would just enter data correctly we wouldn't have to spend so much time validating their data... as for how I would handle a situation where different names are used - like I said, it can be done many different ways and how you do it depends on the framework you're using (if you're using one). Mapping field names can be done in a single method and that method can be reused where ever else you need it.

Comment: No I'm not using a framework.  Yes perhaps I should look at a framework and check how they handle the CRUD and validation operations.